# Angularjs optional navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with 11 pages. Some of them have a nav which is using this code:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav" ng-app="navList">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" ng-controller="navCtrl">
        <li ng-class="navClass('home')"><a href='#/home'>Home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="navClass('about')"><a href='#/about'>About Us</a></li>
        <li ng-class="navClass('contact')"><a href='#/contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

var navList = angular.module('navList', []);

navList.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };        
}]);
```

I don't want this nav on all the pages. What is best solution to handle this situation? Should I show hide DOM element or do I need to remove it when not required?

Comment: If your DOM is small hiding is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely up to you. As @Chandermani said, there's not problem hiding it if your DOM is small. This is how most web-apps that have a fluid layout work. And given the size of your navigation, that's really not going to pose much of a problem.

If you did want to remove it entirely though (which is also fine) you could get angular to do this with the `ng-switch` directive. On your outer element that contains the code you posted, you add the switch, then on the `well` class element above, you add your condition, so for example, you may have

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-switch="smallScreen" ng-app="navList">
    <div class="well sidebar-nav" ng-switch-when="true">
        <ul class="nav nav-list" ng-controller="navCtrl">
            <li ng-class="navClass('home')"><a href='#/home'>Home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="navClass('about')"><a href='#/about'>About Us</a></li>
            <li ng-class="navClass('contact')"><a href='#/contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you'll need a scope variable called `smallScreen` which you set to true or false depending on whether you want to see it.

On another note, it's unusual to have the `ng-app` directive attached to a menu or was this just for demonstration?

Comment: I attached an-app just for demo. Thanks for your answer.